# How to remove request url error from twitter apis in iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I am integrating `twitter api` in my application.

When I am trying to tweet I am getting an error:

```
Request A2C3E4D7-D3E8-47AD-A47C-3AC0DF2975A7 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP    Code=401 The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)
```

I saw there is function defined with `sendUpdate` name. It is looking for parameter `updateID` and it is having zero `(0)` value all time. I am supposing this is occurring due to zero value in `updateID`.

Please help me. How to update in twitter from iPhone application. My consumerkey and consumersecretkey is right.

Thanks

Comment: A 401 error is returned for authentication failures. You have obtained your OAuth access token and access token secret before attempting your status update, correct?